# How can I use preventDefault for a javascript function called from server side

Tags: javascript, c#, ascx

I wanted to call a javascript function from my server side but it reload my page it's normal I have to use `event.preventDefault()`. When I try to use `event.preventDefault()` it doesn't work I have an error. So how can I prevent the reload of my page for a function which is called from server side ?

**talk.js**

```
function talk(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("toto")
}
```

**.ascx file**

```
<script>    
    function checkUser(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        var answer = confirm("answer ?")
        if(answer)
            $("#Btn_Modify").click()
    }

    function modify(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        talk(event)
    }   
</script>

<button runat="server" ID="Btn_check" onclick="checkUser(event)">
    Validation
</button>
<asp:Button runat="server" Visible="false" ID="Btn_Modify" OnClick="Btn_Modify_Click"/>
```

**.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Btn_Modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SOME ACTION BEFORE CALL THE FUNCTION

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>modify(event);</script>");
}
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: What's the error saying?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: `modify(event)` is not bound to an event. So the `event` argument will always be `undefined`. And what you trying to build here? Because this seems like a really bad way to call a function from the server.